# Search for slugs across all models using friendly_id models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, friendly-id

I am using `FriendlyId` across a bunch of different model. For a particular use-case with usernames, I can't use `FriendlyId` but still want to make sure the username is not being used as a slug in any of those models.

Currently, I have a `.exists` query for each model using FriendlyId. It doesn't feel super efficient, so I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this by just querying the `slugs` column in `friendly_id_slugs` table that the library creates?

I'm on Rails 5.1, Postgres 9.5.x and FriendlyId 5.2.3

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @Ben helped me find the ideal solution. It turns out that FriendlyId has an internal model - `FriendlyId::Slug`, that is backed by the `friendly_id_slugs` table.

So, a query like the following worked for me:

```
FriendlyId::Slug.where(
    sluggable_type: ["Animals", "Plants"]
  )
  .where('lower(slug) = ?', potential_username.downcase)
  .exists?
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a model map it to its table, simply create a `app/models/friendly_id_slug.rb` file, containing :

```
class FriendlyIdSlug < ApplicationRecord
end
```

You then get a standard model active record querying methods (`FriendlyIdSlug.where…`)

Alertnatively, running raw sql would apply :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from friendly_id_slugs etc…")
```

That is, your `.exists?` sounds fair too. If you repeat code for each model, you could make a `app/models/concerns` or `app/lib` class file you'd reuse in the concerned models

Comment: Thanks Ben! The first option seems smart, and the cleanest. Do you see any side-effects of declaring a model where one wasn't declared by the library (other than library doing that in a future version)?

Comment: With the `.exists?` option, I wasn't sure if that was also gonna be the most performant - one query in your solutions vs 5-6 with `exists`?

Comment: well you found out how; wasn't aware of this one; super-clean then!